# How is an OpenID Authenticated user Identified?

Tags: oauth, openid

On a system that I'm working on a user signs up by means of an OpenID/Social Media account (Twitter, Google, Facebook), and then subsequently signs in using that path.  The System comprises of a Back-end (API and database) and several clients (Web Portals, Native Mobile applications, and User-Agent/JavaScript based clients.

These clients will get the Authorization to the Above-mentioned back-end API for a user from a special oAuth2 server.  So to share registration data between the clients this will need stored in a central database, part of the back-end service.  Basically I need to track the users in a database.

Once I have an Access Token from an IdP for a user I can get some details about that user, eg Name and Email address, and I'd store some of that in a local database.  I've previously asked "[what I need to store](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79724/can-i-get-rid-of-storing-user-secrets-by-using-openid-and-what-do-i-need-to-sto)" and didn't get any satisfactory answers, but now I've got a more specific question:  What will the IdP give me to identify the user?  Some kind of unique URI for that user?  An Email Address?  An IdP specific ID string?

I need to figure out how I go from getting an Authentication done against the IdP to getting an Access code from the oAuth service for the back-end.  Once I know what I will have available from the user's IdP I can go to the next step, which is to figure out this part between Authenticating the user and getting an access token from the Authorization server for the API.