# What are the pieces of information delivered in a user profile at the end of a OpenID Connect flow?

Tags: authentication, oauth2, openid-connect, user-management, identity-management

From what I understand about using [OpenID Connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID_Connect) (over [OAuth2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0)), is that we end up with some [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) containing information about the user. That information is transported as a [*JSON Web Token*](https://jwt.io).

➥ What are the pieces of information specifically?

- User’s email?
- User’s mobile phone number?
- User's human name?
- User’s “username” on some system?
- Some kind of unique identifier?

Looking through the OpenID Connect site, such as [this page](https://openid.net/connect/), mysteriously I cannot find any explanation of the payload at the end of a OpenID Connect transaction.

If multiple pieces of private information are provided, is there a way to ask for authorization to provide only a subset such as email address but not phone number, just like granularities of [scope in a OAuth2](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/scope/) request for delegated authorization?

---

Most of what little I know about *OpenID Connect* came from the video presentation, [*OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect (in plain English)*](https://youtu.be/996OiexHze0) by Nate Barbettini of Okta.com. He explains the mechanisms & protocols very well, but did not touch on the actual content/payload.

Comment: Related: [*Can I get rid of storing user secrets by using OpenID, and what do I need to store?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/79724/21184)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost at the right resource!  If you click the [core](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) link on the page you referenced you'll find all the answers you're looking for.

There is a section on the [ID token](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) which contains the claims (attributes) that are defined by the OpenID connect spec.  The only one that matches up to you list is the `sub` (subject) which is a unique identifier for the user.

**So where are the rest?**

The spec defines a set of [standard claims](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims) that match up to the attributes you've mentioned.  In fact, the ID Token is [intended to be extensible](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AdditionalClaims).  As such you can add whatever claims you like to the token.

**Requesting access**

The mechanism for adding various claims to the provided ID token is done (as you've suggested) [using scopes](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims).  Most authentication servers allow the creation of rules that govern which claims are requested by each scope.